# HTML5 for scalable User Interface

Tags: html

How to make scalable user interface using HTML5 and CSS3.Webpage(images,icons etc) should adjust itself according to the device size

I have tried working with svg but not getting desirable output as I am using icons.
Please help.I am working on Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental approach is by using css `@media` [tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Yet, by default, many APIs are available online which give this functionality. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) is the most widely known and easy to use.

Comment: But i've read it does not fully support html5 and css3.apart from using framework are there other solutions

Comment: Yes, as I said, use `@media` tags. They help you adjust to custom screen sizes.

Comment: And FYI, Bootstrap supports most of the HTML5/CSS3 functionality. At least it would support all you'd require.

Comment: Here's a link on media tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score -1):

Creating a scalable and responsive user interface with HTML5 and CSS3 is a common practice, and there are several techniques to achieve this. While SVG is a good choice for scalable images and icons, I'll provide a more comprehensive approach for creating a responsive webpage. Also, consider using a code editor that provides features for web development, as Notepad++ might not have some features like live preview or automatic code completion that can assist in web development.

**1. Use Responsive Meta Tag:**

Include the following meta tag in the  section of your HTML to ensure proper scaling on various devices:

**2. Use Media Queries:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Styles for small screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    /* Styles for medium screens */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    /* Styles for large screens */
}
```

**3. SVG Icons:**
If you're using SVG icons, make sure to set the width and height attributes to make them scalable.

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <!-- Your SVG content here -->
</svg>
```

For alignment and some other display related concerns use flexbox properties to get more scalable User Interface.